# How to print local datetime in Docker logs

Tags: linux, docker

I want to print the localdatetim in my Docker logs. I tried the code below, but I always get time in UTC.
Lets notice that I'm actually in Rome.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

```
build:
stage: build
script:
 - docker info
 - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
 - echo "Project_data = \""$CI_IMAGE_COMMIT_TAG"\"" > version.py
 - docker build --pull --tag $CI_IMAGE_COMMIT_TAG .
 - export current_date=$(TZ=Europe/Rome date)
 - echo $current_date
 - docker push $CI_IMAGE_COMMIT_TAG
tags:
 - docker-socket
 - build
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use TZ environment variable:
With docker file

```
ENV TZ=Europe/Rome
```

With docker compose:

```
environment:
   - TZ=Europe/Rome
```

Comment: i have other file in my env ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=$WORK_DIR/airflow AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER=$WORK_DIR/airflow/dags how should i added please?

Comment: do you have an idea? please? @CimaW

Comment: @biwia: You can add multiple ENV variables: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

try this:  ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=$WORK_DIR/airflow AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER=$WORK_DIR/airflow/dags TZ=Europe/Rome